# Advice needed for Skinny to Muscular

Tags: health

I'm very skinny boy ( Height 5'11" weight 65kgs ) . I'm daily eating only 2 meals a day due to work . Is there any alternative solution for transforming to athletic or physically fit body??  I can't exercise regularly also !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue - 6 foot 150 and although this isn't *that* skinny, I can't gain a pound for the life of me.

It is impossible to attain what you are asking without essentially destroying your health which, in my opinion, is not worth it.

### Methods I've tried:

**Non healthy**
- weight gainers
- pre workout supplements 
- lift 3 to 4 x a week

**Healthy**
- Eat often and generously of all kinds of healthy foods (3 large meals)
- lift 3 to 4 x a week

And I've never had any luck gaining weight. Although, I did get pretty toned.

I believe in our situation and others alike, it is necessary to hit the weight room HARD for minimum of 5 days a week while eating as much as possible (4 generous meals and snacks in between).

Of course, everyone takes slightly different.

On a side note, you don't *need* a bigger body. You're good as you are. If someone thinks otherwise , they are no good.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't eat properly and exercise then no, there is no chance you'll transform to an athletic or physically fit body. I try to be helpful and supportive but aside from diet and nutrition, what other options do you have?

Not having time really isn't much of an excuse. You could have decent progress with a commitment of this level:

- Training 3 times a week for ~45 minutes.
- 20 minutes a day prepping some decent meals for yourself.
- A marginal increase in grocery shopping.

But no, if you are going to eat two (probably bad) meals a day and not exercise, you will remain deconditioned. Hopefully you won't suffer health problems, but you might.

Comment: It is possible for me to workout 3 times a day and daily I can arrange 1 hour for cooking. From now on I'm going to take this seriously!! Thanks for your advice! :-)

Comment: @user75508 you might want to ask separate questions for those, or search around. "what's a good starting strength program" and "what are basic diet changes I can make to support a fitness program". For both of those, make sure you put in what you're doing now and for how long.

Comment: I'm eating almost vegetarian foods!! Does this affects my health gaining decision?? Is there any alternative way like taking protein powders ?? I'm mentally affected by My low BMI of 19.6 although I'm financially independent. I started thinking myself that my appearance is a basic hurdle for my career and I can't influence my employees due to My physique. If I start serious workouts and food intake schedules , Is there any chance of change in my appearance starting from my facecut?? (My forehead skull and cheeks are also thin :-( ) I started thinking to take any medical treatments :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to workout and eat a lot (as you said you could in the comments on Eric's answer), you'll get bigger, barring rare metabolic conditions. Just get a beginner strength program like Starting Strength and eat >2800 calories a day with 40% of that being protein (and protein powder is acceptable).

You also mentioned "medical treatments" in the comments. There are no medical treatments that will make you look more athletic without exercising. Even illegal steroids require you to lift weights to see any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't eat during work or you don't have time to, I suggest you to prepare your shaker with everything you need for a meal.

Check this out :
[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy-dRa9nhz4)
[Muscle and Brawn](http://muscleandbrawn.com/1000-calorie-homemade-weight-gainer-shake/)